# Transparency/Alpha with haskell GLUT bindings

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut

Using the [Haskell GLUT binding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT), I modified the [Hello World example](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/blob/master/examples/RedBook4/Hello.hs) in two ways:

1. Added `WithAlphaComponent` to `initialDisplayMode`.
2. Changed color to a `Color4` with `0.5` opacity.

I would expect it to display a semi-transparent white square with the background red showing through. Instead it shows a solid white square, as if the opacity is being ignored. I can't figure out why this doesn't work?

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
   -- clear all pixels
   clear [ ColorBuffer ]

   -- draw white polygon (rectangle) with corners at
   -- (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)

   -- CHANGE #2
   color (Color4 1.0 1.0 (1.0 :: GLfloat) 0.5)

   -- resolve overloading, not needed in "real" programs
   let vertex3f = vertex :: Vertex3 GLfloat -> IO ()
   renderPrimitive Polygon $ mapM_ vertex3f [
      Vertex3 0.25 0.25 0.0,
      Vertex3 0.75 0.25 0.0,
      Vertex3 0.75 0.75 0.0,
      Vertex3 0.25 0.75 0.0]

   -- don't wait!
   -- start processing buffered OpenGL routines
   flush

myInit :: IO ()
myInit = do
   -- select clearing color
   clearColor $= Color4 0.7 0 0 0

   -- initialize viewing values
   matrixMode $= Projection
   loadIdentity
   ortho 0 1 0 1 (-1) 1

-- Declare initial window size, position, and display mode (single buffer and
-- RGBA). Open window with "hello" in its title bar. Call initialization
-- routines. Register callback function to display graphics. Enter main loop and
-- process events.
main :: IO ()
main = do
   _ <- getArgsAndInitialize
   -- CHANGE #1
   initialDisplayMode $= [ SingleBuffered, RGBMode, WithAlphaComponent ]
   initialWindowSize $= Size 250 250
   initialWindowPosition $= Position 100 100
   _ <- createWindow "hello"
   myInit
   displayCallback $= display
   mainLoop
```

Comment: You probably need to enable alpha blending. In C, this is done with `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`. Not sure, how you do this in Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [Alpha.hs](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/blob/master/examples/RedBook4/Alpha.hs) example.

```
-- Initialize alpha blending function.
myInit :: IO ()
myInit = do
   blend $= Enabled
   blendFunc $= (SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha)
   shadeModel $= Flat
   clearColor $= Color4 0 0 0 0
```